# Remove the line under dropdown in react-native

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I have a dropdown used with react-native-material-dropdown and I can't find a way to remove the underline of the label... What am I missing ? Thanks for your help
I tried `inputContainerStyle={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}`

and

```
lineWidth={0}
activeLineWidth={0}
disabledLineWidth={0}
```

but.. no success.
my code :

```
<View style={[styles.centeredView, {marginTop:0}]}>
              <MaterialDropdown
                data={data_dropdown}
                baseColor="#212121"
                labelFontSize={17}
                textColor="#212121"
                itemColor="#212121"
                selectedItemColor="#000"
                backgroundColor="transparent"
                pickerStyle={styles.dropdownPickerStyle}
                affixTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                itemTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                labelTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                containerStyle={[styles.dropdownContainerStyle]}
                lineWidth={0}
                activeLineWidth={0}
                disabledLineWidth={0}
                itemCount={10}
                dropdownPosition={-4.5}
                labelExtractor={({ label }) => label}
                valueExtractor={({ value }) => value}
                propsExtractor={({ props }, index) => props}
                onChangeText={(value) => this.choiceAction(value)}
                useNativeDriver={true}
              />
              <Image
                source={require("../../assets/images/btn-flights-listing.png")}
                style={{position:'absolute',
                        width: "35%",
                        height: 30,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"}}/>
            </View>
```

style :

```
dropdownPickerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: "auto",
  },
dropdownContainerStyle: {
    width: "75%",
    zIndex: 100,
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
  },
```

[image: Underline dropdown]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ciao, to remove the underline you have to pass `underlineColor='transparent'` to `MaterialDropdown` component like:

```
<MaterialDropdown
   underlineColor='transparent'
   ...
/>
```

Comment: This is perfect answer but @giovanni-esposito tell me one thing i saw the npm documentation of this library, there is no any prop like underlineColor, where did you find that. Thanks by the way.